# Excel mapping and create a new column

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, formula

Excel file columns:

```
A                  B                  C
2                  two                3
5                  five               8
3                  three              10
8                  eight              11
12                 one                15
```

I want to create a new column `D`in same file like below:

```
A                  B                  C               D
2                  two                3               three
5                  five               8               eight
3                  three              10              
8                  eight              11
12                 one                15
```

I want to map `C` and `A` and if there's a match `D` takes values of `B`.

Example: Value `3` in `C` is present in `A`, so `D` will take corresponding `B` value `three`.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this just a `VLOOKUP` of the value in `column 3` from `column 1` resulting in the value in `column 2`?  Also, it might benefit you to normalize the column names to letters, as is standard in Excel - ala, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, respectively in this case.

Comment: Thanks @gravity, I made the changes

Comment: ^ VLOOKUP, wrapped in IFERROR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So building on BigBen's additional suggestion of using an `IFERROR`, I believe you want something akin to this in Column `D`:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1, A:B, 2, FALSE), "")`
... and then drag down the formula throughout Column `D`

Now, there are some assumptions being made here:

1. Your data does not have any header row, ala the data starts in Row 1, not Row 2
2. You want empty/blank values where there is no exact match (this is BigBen's `IFERROR` suggestion).  Your current question layout seems to suggest this.  Otherwise, you'll get `#N/A` in all those blank cells in Column D.

EDIT: To confirm, I used your data (though I started in Row 2), and here's how it looked after -

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If one has DA-functionality you could use:

**1)** - Excluding empty cells using `FILTER`:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=FILTER(B1:B5,COUNTIF(C1:C5,A1:A5)>0)
```

**2)** - Including empty cells using `XLOOKUP`:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=XLOOKUP(C1:C5,A1:A5,B1:B5,"")
```

---

If one does **not** have access to DA-functionality you could use:

**1)** - Excluding empty cells using `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `SMALL`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$5,SMALL(IFNA(MATCH(C$1:C$5,A$1:A$5,0),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

> ***Note 1*** - This needs to be array entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
>
> ***Note 2*** - Alternatively, one could use a non-array entered approach including `AGGREGATE` as per @basic: `=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,MATCH(C$1:C$5,A$1:A$5,0),ROW(A1))),"")`

**2)** - Including empty cells using `VLOOKUP`:

Please refer to the other answer given by @Gravity [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61503982/9758194).

---

Basically the difference between both approaches could be vizualised like:

[image]

Comment: Summary of DA - basically `FILTER` is the best thing that happened to Excel, based on its usage in Stack Overflow answers haha.

Comment: It's a shame it's not included in `Excel 2019`, hence I had to resort to `Excel Online`. But you are right, it's very handy.

Comment: Thanks @JvdV, unfortunately don't have DA-functionality, will try it for sure, and thanks for the great explanation !!

Comment: @JvdV Out of curiosity - why don't you use the ```AGGREGATE (15; 6; ...)``` function in non-DA option 1 instead of ```SMALL()```? This would allow you to abandon ctrl + shift + enter and the embedded ```IFNA``` function.

Comment: No worries @pc_pyr, I hope I made clear through my revision that my `INDEX` and `MATCH` approach does not involve any DA-functionality. Good luck with your project =)

Comment: @basic, simply because I haven't thought about it =). In that case `=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,MATCH(C$1:C$5,A$1:A$5,0),ROW(A1))),"")` in `D1` would do. Feel free to add an answer. I'll upvote it =)

Comment: @JvdV No, no, this formula will not be very different from yours, you can add it as another option to your answer. Just don't forget to specify for your formula that it must be array entered.